# iOS custom UIView access properties in code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

So I've created a custom UIView subclass and have it assigned to a UIView in my main storyboard. When the view loads everything is displayed properly.

The issue I'm having is that I need to be able to access properties of said custom UIView since the view is data driven.

JSON_table.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface JSON_table : UIView
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchbar;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *table_view;

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *data_header;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *data_list;
@end
```

JSON_table.m:

```
#import "JSON_table.h"
@implementation JSON_table
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"JSON_table" owner:self options:nil];
        [self addSubview:self.view];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

(I know I'm missing delegates for tableview, ill be adding these later)

The issue I'm having is when I right click on my UIView on my storyboard I get:
[image]

The problem is when I try to connect "view" to my header file "
ViewController.h" it doesn't let me create a IBOutlet, so I cannot reference my view and its properties in code.

This is what I am trying to accomplish:
[image]
"Table" is of type UIView

Idea:

Would this have anything to do with the UIView being on the second view in my storyboard? I noticed that I don't seem to have any problem attaching to anything on the first page, but the second one I can't.
[image]

Comment: Based on your question, I think it would make more sense for you to use `UIViewController`.

Comment: @ChrisLoonam I need the custom control to be able to be self contained and there may be more then one on the screen at one time. Wouldn't UIViewController limit me to one?

Comment: control drag from the File Owner box to your view object in the IB and connect it to view

Comment: @Chase I ctr dragged from "File's Owner" To "View" on the xib editor page. it gave me the option to connect outlet "View" but it had a white dot indicating it was already connected. But I did it again to make sure. But I still don't get a outlet on my storyboard. See above edit.

Comment: @theshadow124 so when you control drag from your view object in IB to your ViewController it doesn't let you?

Comment: i mean the viewcontroller.m or .h file

Comment: @chase Yes. Nothing comes up, even if I type out a IBOutlet

Comment: @theshadow124 click on your file owner box and look at the identity inspector. The custom class should be the name of the class file you want to create outlets too without the extension

Comment: @Chase This is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only connect the outlets of a view to it's class object. You are trying to connect outlets of JSON_table object to UIViewController object.

If you need to access those properties in UIViewController object. You need to import

```
JSON_table.h
```

in your view controller. And create and instantiate a object of it.

```
JSON_table * customView = [[JSON_table alloc]init];
```

Now you can access all the properties of it as:

`customView.searchbar, customView.view` etc.

**Added by theshadow124:**

Thanks to everyone who attempted to help me solve my problem. Due to being fairly new to coding for iOS I didn't realize I had to assign a custom class to every UIViewController in my storyboard(I thought they they would inherit from the base if I didn't specify). simply creating a new subclass of UIViewController and assigning it under the Identity inspector fixed my problem and now I can properly assign outlets.

Im going to accept this answer because it was one of the issues I ran into after fixing the subclass on the storyboard issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that in assistant editor your are opening the same class that your custom class is contained in .

Comment: I have the controls and view linked in the custom view shown in the code above. I'm trying to connect a outlet for the custom view once I've put it on the storyboard so the main code can pass data into the properties of the view

Comment: yes i understand that , i mean make sure that your class that your are trying to connect the custom view to it is the same that contain the custom view in the storyboard

Comment: In the assistant viewer, if i set it to automatic for my storyboard it will open a file "UIViewController.h" that is that standard apple header file for a UIViewController. I have all my other outlets in "ViewController.h", the same file that receives viewDidLoad event

Comment: okey so , i tried your code , you are right it will not connect the custom view as an outlet , so please do the following and it will work : press ctrl button and right mouse button at the same time , drag the mouse to your .h file and it will connect it , please if it work mark as right answer

Comment: i right clicked while holding ctr. on the UIView(Json_Table) and tried to drag to my ViewController.h both on the left hand side and the assistant editor on the right and it still will not let me connect it